# git log specific file with pretty format

Tags: git, powershell, cmd

I don't understand how to fix on cmd or powershell

```
git log myfile.txt --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset' -n 10
```

as I get this error

```
fatal: option '--pretty=format:%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset' must come before non-option arguments
```

Update : myfile.txt is not the output file : it is the SOURCE file for which I want GIT HISTORY

Comment: I could be wrong, but, I think git made a change where `--` has to be at the end of the command .. Have you tried `git log myfile.txt -n 10 --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset'` ?

Comment: Are you still having the same issue?  Or did swiping the `--` to the end of the command help?

Comment: @Zak just tried your suggestion still get error : fatal: option '-n' must come before non-option arguments

Comment: Try `git log --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset' -n 10 > myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have your options mixed up with the log file itself...  You're trying to write to a custom log file.   The log file needs to be at the end and "written to" using `>`.

```
git log --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset' -n 10 > myfile.txt
```

I generally like to call them "log" files by using the `.log` format .. But that's just preference.

```
git log --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset - %s%Creset' -n 10 > my_git_log.log
```

**UPDATE**

When sourcing history -- Should still be at the end .. IE

```
git log --all -- /path/to/file/myfile.txt
```

Comment: myfile.txt is not the output file : it is the SOURCE file for which I want GIT HISTORY